# jQuery character count - function not being called

Tags: javascript, jquery, forms

I'm creating a jQuery function to count the amount of characters in a text field and output the number. But it does not seem to be called on key release. The page with the text field is an external page that is being included into `index.php` and the `js` is being included from an external `js` file.

```
  $('#commentField').keyup(function () {
    alert("functionCalled");
    var max = 500;
    var len = $(this).val().length;
    if (len >= max) {
      $('#charNum').html(' you have reached the limit');
    } else {
      var char = max - len;
      $('#charNum').text(char + ' characters left');
    }
  });
```

Text area:

```
<input type="text" name="commentArea" placeholder="Comment..." autofocus="autofocus" id="commentField"/>
```

The `div` to be populated:

```
<div id="charNum">here</div>
```

The external `js` file is being access fine but the function does not seem to be called. Why is this not working?

Comment: You don't get the alert ?

Comment: What is the value of $('#commentField').length just before you add the keyup listener ?

Comment: No I don't get the alert.

Comment: Run this - alert($('#commentField').length);

Comment: can you provide jsfiddle? or try with `.on(keypress,...`

Comment: Works for me http://jsfiddle.net/vEkTC/

Comment: Have you tried using a debugger such as firebug?

Comment: @Zach the output is `0`

Comment: Can whoever voted it down please explain why?

Comment: @Colin747, "included into index.php" means that you are using php function `include`. But that is not case, if James solution worked, because you are importing code via AJAX. You should tell us that.

Comment: @MiljanPuzović thanks for pointing that out, didn't think to specify whether I was using `include` or `AJAX`, my mistake.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If it is dynamic content then you need to call .on.  However, I would change 'body' to something closer to the element in the dom.

```
$('body').on('keyup','#commentField',function () {
    alert("functionCalled");
    var max = 500;
    var len = $(this).val().length;
    if (len >= max) {
      $('#charNum').html(' you have reached the limit');
    } else {
      var char = max - len;
      $('#charNum').text(char + ' characters left');
    }
});
```

Answer (score 2):

`char` is a reserved word in javascript, so your keyup function is not compiling. Try using a different name.

edit:

It seems to work on [this fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/HcNyn/).

Comment: I've changed the variable name and I am still not getting the alert.

Comment: Hmm, let me look into it further.

Comment: @Nolo, James got the solution. Colin importing JS code via AJAX, and is this basic problem in that case.

Answer (score 1):

Is your event handler inside of a document ready function?

```
$(function () {

   //put your code here

});
```

Next, does your input exist on the page at the time of your event binding?  In other words, is your element added dynamically?  If so, try out event delegation.

Comment: Yes it is in a `(document).ready` function, it is being added dynamically.